# Opencart: After placing / confirming an order, where in the code is the stock quantity updated?

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to update the ean value every time a product is purchased (ie, order confirmed). However, no matter how hard I look I can't seem to find any sort of code that updates the product quantity in the database.

Where is the stock updated?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via API in: `catalog/controller/api/order.php`
triggering function:
`$this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory($json['order_id'], $order_status_id);`
In: `catalog/model/checkout/order.php`